# jQuery change duplicating action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm stuck in a problem that seems to be very simple to solve, but I doesn't figured out. I have 3 `radio` each one have their data attribute for the selected payment method, but the problem is, in jQuery code I need to submit an AJAX request, based on the selected radio `switch`. But If I click in the first radio, give and go to 3rd radio, I get 2 POST requests. For the first radio and 3rd, when should be 1. o.O

```
$("#payment-form input[name=payment_option]").change(function() {
var payment_method = $("input[name=payment_option]:checked").data('payment-method');

$("#checkout-button").prop('disabled', false);
console.log(payment_method);
switch (payment_method) {

    // First radio
    case 'pagseguro':
        $("#paypal-button").css('display', 'none');
        $("#checkout-button").css('display', 'block');
        $("#checkout-button").prop('disabled', false);

        $checkout_button.click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://usercp.dev/doacao/fazer-doacao/pagamento/pagseguro',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response) {
                    if (response.success) {
                        var code = response.transaction_code
                        PagSeguroLightbox({
                            code: code
                        }, {
                            success: function(transactionCode) {
                                $.post("http://usercp.dev/doacao/fazer-doacao/pagamento/received", {
                                        payment_token: response.payment_token,
                                        payment_method: response.payment_method,
                                        transaction_code: transactionCode,
                                        transaction_done: response.success,
                                        csrf_token: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                                    })
                                    .done(function(response) {
                                        if (!response.success) {
                                            toastr.error("Oops!", response.error)
                                        }
                                        window.location.replace(response.redirect);
                                    }, 'json');
                            },
                            abort: function() {
                                toastr.options.positionClass = 'toast-top-center';
                                toastr.info("Você cancelou a operação de pagamento.");
                                $(".loader").addClass('hidden');
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        toastr.options.positionClass = 'toast-top-center';
                        toastr.error(response.error);
                        if (response.redirect !== "") {
                            window.location.replace(response.redirect);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            $(".loader").removeClass('hidden');
            $("#checkout-button").prop('disabled', true);
            $("#checkout-button").html('<i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-fw"></i>');
        });

        break;

    // PayPal have their one button, so work without errors.
    case 'paypal':
        $("#paypal-button").css('display', 'block');
        $("#checkout-button").css('display', 'none');
        break;

    // PicPay I try to use the same button as PagSeguro (first radio) 
    // but as I mentioned above, 
    // If selected PagSeguro first and jump to PicPay I'll see to post requests (one for PagSeguro and another for PicPay). I want to fix this.
    case 'picpay':
        $("#paypal-button").css('display', 'none');
        $("#checkout-button").css('display', 'block');
        $("#checkout-button").prop('disabled', false);
        $checkout_button.click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://usercp.dev/doacao/fazer-doacao/pagamento/picpay',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response) {
                    if (!response.success) {
                        toastr.error("Oops!", response.error)
                    }
                    window.location.replace(response.redirect);
                }
            });
            $(".loader").removeClass('hidden');
            $("#checkout-button").prop('disabled', true);
            $("#checkout-button").html('<i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-fw"></i>');
        });
        break;
}

   });
```

HTML is simple.

```
<input type="radio" class="radio" name="payment_option" id="payment_option" data-payment-method="pagseguro">

<input type="radio" class="radio" name="payment_option" id="payment_option" data-payment-method="paypal">

<input type="radio" class="radio" name="payment_option" id="payment_option" data-payment-method="picpay">
```

Comment: The purpose of an ID is to point towards a unique element.

Comment: Hmmmm. That's all I need, thank you @Script47. You're right I'll added custom id for each payment_option ID =). Sometimes our mind don't work for simple issues >_>

Comment: Won't that still trigger the change handler?

Comment: @Thijs I'd assume so, I was merely pointing out an issue with the OP's HTML.

Answer (score 1):

So you have 2 buttons that trigger a different ajax request each, and you want to be able to trigger ajax A, then trigger ajax B and cancel ajax A.

First you must understand that Ajax is async. That means that when the ajax starts, it triggers a thread of actions separate from your main thread where all your javascript exists.

If you want to cancel A when B is triggered, or cancel B when A is triggered, you need to keep track of your ajax requests.

The simplest way I can imagine is to put your ajax inside a variable

```
var currentAjax = $.ajax(/* Ajax A */)
```

Then when you trigger a new ajax you can do something like this to get rid of the previous one

```
if (currentAjax) { currentAjax.abort() }

currentAjax = $.ajax(/* the new ajax you selected */)
```

to sum it up better

we have a variable (it could be global for simplicity's sake) that contains the last activated ajax

```
var currentPayAjax;

$checkout_button.click(function() {

    // an inefficient but doable way to try and cancel any potential previous get      
    try { currentPayAjax.abort() } catch(err){}

    switch (payment_method) {    
        case 'pagseguro':

        currentPayAjax = $.ajax({/* stuff A */})

        break;
        case 'picpay':

        currentPayAjax = $.ajax({/* stuff B */})

        break;
    }
)}
```

Comment: Sorry, I leave and forgot to answer. But doesn't work. I'll try a new approach, if works, I'll publish the answer.